# Wierd behaviour of Listview in android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

main.xml file is:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewMovies"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:divider="#0EBDFE"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp"
    android:fadingEdge="none" />
```

and this is my onclick event of listview:

```
listViewMovies.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int pos,
                long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("MainActivity", "clicked position: " + pos);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    MovieDetailsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("id", arrayIds.get(pos));
        intent.putExtra("name", arrayTitles.get(pos));
        intent.putExtra("release_date", arrayReleaseDate.get(pos));
        intent.putExtra("casts", arrayAbridgedCast.get(pos));
        intent.putExtra("critics_consensus",
                    arrayCriticsConsensus.get(pos));
        intent.putExtra("synopsis", arraySynopsis.get(pos));
        intent.putExtra("trailor", arrayLinks.get(pos));
        intent.putExtra("thumb_img", arrayThumbPosters.get(pos));
        intent.putExtra("profile_img", arrayProfilePosters.get(pos));
            startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

But sometimes click event is called but sometimes it is not.

Can anyone suggest me what should the problem?

Comment: post ur problem clearly tell brief friend.

Comment: check that when you execute `onItemclick()` you get value of each field (value which you are passing using intent) or not.

Comment: main problem is click event of listview item is not occurring at all time.

Comment: yes i have checked them...all values that are in intent extra are available.

Comment: Offtopic, but don't ever use wrap_content on any AdapterView. It causes bad performance by measuring all children after each one added. Use fixed sizes, weights, or match_parent.

Comment: @Doctoror: Thanks for your advice, i will definitely use this.

Answer (score -1):

Are you inflating any xml file having button for your list items. If so then button prevents the click event on list item. To overcome this you can add

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
```

hope it will help you..

Comment: no i have pny one imageview and three textview in the listview item